# Assembler instructions and compilers

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, cortex-m

I wonder why different compilers use different assembly instructions.

For instance I work with cc3200 from TI which has Cortex-M4 inside and here is a real piece of code from SDK:

```
#if defined(ewarm)
#define BACK_UP_ARM_REGISTERS() {             \
        __asm(" push {r0-r12,LR} \n" \
          " mov32 r1, vault_arm_registers \n" \
          " mrs  r0,msp \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,psp \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #4] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,primask \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #12] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,faultmask \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #16] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,basepri \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #20] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,control \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #24] \n"); \
          }
#endif

#if defined(ccs)
#define BACK_UP_ARM_REGISTERS() {     \
        __asm(" push {r0-r12,LR} \n" \
          " movw r1, vault_arm_registers \n" \
          " movt r1, vault_arm_registers \n" \
          " mrs  r0,msp \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,psp \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #4] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,primask \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #12] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,faultmask \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #16] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,basepri \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #20] \n" \
          " mrs  r0,control \n" \
          " str  r0,[r1, #24] \n"); \
          }
#endif
```

As you can see these two macros have different instructions to move 32 bits into register. CCS supports two 16-bit instructions `movw` and `movt` whilst EWARM --- one for 32-bit movement `mov32`. Empirically I have found out that GCC supports neither of them(actually it supports `movw` and `movt` but this code does not compile because of error `constant expression required`). So the question is why is it so?  I thought that the instruction set is fixed for a processor. Moreover I was not able to find cortex-m4 instructions which are specific to GCC, EWARM or CCS, how can I reveal them?

Comment: The instruction set is fixed by the hardware but the compilers can use whatever instruction format they want. And don't have to support all of the processor variants. Don't know about ARM, but for x86 processors gcc doesn't use Intel's assembly format unless you explicitly ask for it.

Comment: dont know what mov32 is and this could be thumb mode vs arm mode, but the push looks wrong.

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the program that parses the ascii file, so you need to match the assembly language to the assembler (toolchain).  then of course inline assembly adds a whole new level of pain.  (and is compiler specific).  so no surprise whatsoever that gcc/gas (gnu) does not support some other compilers or assemblers language.

Comment: so if you want to use ti code you likely need to stay in ti's sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that in addition to the instructions provided by the architecture the assembler usually adds some pseudo instruction to simplify the language. In this case `mov32` is assembled as a `movw` instruction followed by a `movt`. Sometimes the different assemblers for an architecture do implement the same pseudo instructions and sometimes not.